# Bitpay with laravel

Tags: laravel, bitcoin, cryptocurrency, bitpay

how can i use bitpay with Laravel , i found this 'https://packagist.org/packages/vrajroham/laravel-bitpay' but i have this problem on install :

**Problem 1
    - bitpay/sdk v3.0.1910 requires bitpay/key-utils ^1.0 -> satisfiable by bitpay/key-utils[v1.0.1908].
    - bitpay/sdk v3.1.1910 requires bitpay/key-utils ^1.0 -> satisfiable by bitpay/key-utils[v1.0.1908].
    - bitpay/sdk v3.2.1910 requires bitpay/key-utils ^1.0 -> satisfiable by bitpay/key-utils[v1.0.1908].
    - bitpay/sdk v3.2.1911 requires bitpay/key-utils ^1.0 -> satisfiable by bitpay/key-utils[v1.0.1908].
    - bitpay/key-utils v1.0.1908 requires ext-bcmath * -> the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for bitpay/sdk ~3.0 -> satisfiable by bitpay/sdk[v3.0.1910, v3.1.1910, v3.2.1910, v3.2.1911].**

Comment: You may need to install PHP extension bcmath

Answer (score 0):

You can use this SDK provided by BitPay to make requests to their api: [Bitpay SDK](https://github.com/bitpay/php-bitpay-client-v2).
There you will find a very good documented [guide](https://github.com/bitpay/php-bitpay-client-v2/blob/master/GUIDE.md) that explains step by step how to install and use the SDK.

I will leave here the steps **only to install** the SDK.

---

**BitPay SDK Installation**

- Install [composer](https://getcomposer.org/).

  `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`
- Install BitPay SDK using composer.

  `php composer.phar require bitpay/sdk:~3.0`
- Alternatively, you can install the SDK via composer by hand. Add the following to your composer.json file:

```
{
    ...
    "require": {
        ...
        "bitpay/sdk": "~3.0"
    }
    ...
}
```

- Once you have added this, just run: 
   `php composer.phar update bitpay/sdk`

---

**Final Note**
After following these steps you will be able to generate a key required to make requests. More information [here](https://github.com/bitpay/php-bitpay-client-v2/blob/master/examples/ConfigGenerator.php).